# Rank Of A Matrix Under Special Conditions

Tags: matrices, algorithms, determinant, matrix-equations

Let A be a $N*N$ matrix. Now A is defined in a special manner:

Each row of A is defined by two integers L and R ($0\le L,R\le {N-1}$), such that all elements from the $L^{th}$ to the $R^{th}$ are all $1$'s in this row. All rest elements of thisrow are $0$.

Like for example if the row identifiers for our matrix are $[0,1], [2,3], [0,0], [4,4]$. Our matrix will look like:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now I have to find the rank of such a matrix in $GF(2)$. I am aware of a $O(N^2)$ solution to the above problem. But I was curious if we could do better because of the special form of the matrix?

Comment: This is that [CodeChef problem](http://www.codechef.com/FEB14/problems/CHSEQ22) again, isn't it? Cf. e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667632/creating-new-sequence/667670#667670 My guess is $O(N)$ memory and $O(N\ln N)$ time